# How to import dates in a certain format

Tags: r

Here is a small data frame:

```
new_incidents <- 
structure(list(id = c(18304380L, 18304383L, 18304385L, 18304388L, 
18304390L, 18304392L), crime_type = c("COMMON ASSAULT", "AGGRAV ASSAULT", 
"INVESTIGATE", "DISORDERLY", "COMMON ASSAULT", "COMMON ASSAULT"
), incident_date = c("9/1/17", "9/1/17", "9/1/17", "9/1/17", 
"9/1/17", "9/1/17")), .Names = c("id", "crime_type", "incident_date"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

> glimpse(new_incidents)
Observations: 6
Variables: 3
$ id            <int> 18304380, 18304383, 18304385, 18304388, 18304390, 18304392
$ crime_type    <chr> "COMMON ASSAULT", "AGGRAV ASSAULT", "INVESTIGATE", "DISORDERLY", "COMMON ASSAULT", "CO...
$ incident_date <chr> "9/1/17", "9/1/17", "9/1/17", "9/1/17", "9/1/17", "9/1/17"
```

I have a previously defined date that I want to filter on

```
some_date <- as.Date("2017-09-01")
```

I tried changing new_incidents$incident_date

```
new_incidents$incident_date <- as.Date(new_incidents$incident_date)

> glimpse(new_incidents)
Observations: 6
Variables: 3
$ id            <int> 18304380, 18304383, 18304385, 18304388, 18304390, 18304392
$ crime_type    <chr> "COMMON ASSAULT", "AGGRAV ASSAULT", "INVESTIGATE", "DISORDERLY", "COMMON ASSAULT", "CO...
$ incident_date <date> 9-01-17, 9-01-17, 9-01-17, 9-01-17, 9-01-17, 9-01-17
```

Now if I try to filter on some_date

```
new_incidents_smdate <- filter(new_incidents, incident_date == some_date)
```

returns an empty data frame.

Looks like an issue with date formatting. How can I read in and filter a data frame based on the date format some_date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I see is that you column *incident_date* is as *character* type and *some_date* variable is on *Date* class type. These comparison will return false, always, thus, the filter will indeed return a empty data frame.

You have two options:

- Work with you column *incident_date* as *character*. But, for this, the *some_date* has to be *character* as well. Thus `as.character(as.Date(...))`
- Work with your column *incident_date* as *Date*. You have to cast the elements of the column: `new_incidents$incident_date = as.Date(new_incidents$incident_date,
  format = "%M/%d/%y")`

Answer (score 0):

I changed the line for changing to date format to this:

```
new_incidents$incident_date <- as.Date(new_incidents$incident_date, format = "%M/%d/%y")
```

So I added format parameter.

Wonder if there's a better way, such as setting this format on import rather than taking up a whole new line?

Comment: what do you mean by import? Importing from the file from disk?